# on load more click show more products of same category in search in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, search

I have load more button in search after user search that load more button is coming on that click show that category products in magento2

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you can see the image there is load more button when i click on that button it should open the products of same category of the products that are coming in search

Comment: there is search button on typing A name products are coming new I want to show the products of that same category on load more click